# Java reflection: get class of field

Tags: java, reflection

I have a method that requires something like `Double.class` as one of its inputs;

e.g.

```
someOutput = SomeObj.someMethod("parameter",Double.class);
```

I have another class that has a bunch of fields of different datatypes that I'd like to feed as input to this method  in stead of explicitly writing `Double.class` of `Integer.class` etc etc.

I know this involves java reflection, but I'm not quite sure how to do what I want.  I'm trying something like this but it isn't working:

```
for(Field field : Class.forName(MyClassWithLotsOfFields.class.getCanonicalName()).getFields()){ 
   someOutput = SomeObj.someMethod("parameter",field.getClass());
  //Do more stuff here...
}
```

but `field.getClass()` is not giving me the actual class of the field from `MyClassWithLotsOfFields` but instead `java.lang.reflect.Field`

any ideas for how to do what I want?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing `Class.forName(MyClassWithLotsOfFields.class.getCanonicalName())` instead of just `MyClassWithLotsOfFields.class`?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I suspect they may have been thinking that you could have gotten the answer by reading the javadoc for `Field`, which you already know about.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need [`Field#getType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29).

> Returns a `Class` object that identifies the declared type for the field
>   represented by this `Field` object.

`getClass()` is a method inherited from `Object` that returns the type of the object itself.