# Check if Collection of DTOs sorted by a given field

Tags: java, sorting, reflection, comparator

I have to write tests for a pagination and sorting GET ALL endpoint that I have. The following is the simple DTO that I am working with:

```java
public class TransactionDto {
  private Long id;
  private Long sourceAccountId;
  private Long targetAccountId;
  private BigDecimal amount;
  private Currency currency;
}
```

Of importance to this discussion is that *all* of those fields are `Comparable`, including the type `Currency`, which is an `enum` I have created with about 300 different currency symbols.

Now, I want to ensure that a REST controller endpoint has returned a `Collection` of these `TransactionDto` instances in a sorted manner. After reading [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-check-if-list-sorted) I learned of Guava's `Comparators` class and, specifically, the `isInOrder` method ([doc link](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Comparators.html#isInOrder-java.lang.Iterable-java.util.Comparator-)).

I have to begin with the field name of `TransactionDto` to sort by, and I also have this simple `SortOrder` enum to designate ascending or descending sort order:

```java
public enum SortOrder {
    ASC, DESC
}
```

This is what I have so far, and I am stuck on the fact that the `Method.invoke()` method returns raw `Object` instances.

```java
private boolean collectionIsSortedByFieldInGivenDirection(Collection<TransactionDto> transactionDtos,
                                                            String sortByField, SortOrder sortOrder){
    return Comparators.isInOrder(transactionDtos, (t1, t2) -> compareFieldsInGivenOrder(t1, t2, sortByField, sortOrder));
}

private int compareFieldsInGivenOrder(TransactionDto transactionOne, TransactionDto transactionTwo,
                                        String sortByField, SortOrder sortOrder){
    try {
      PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(sortByField, TransactionDto.class);
      Method appropriateGetter = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
      Object transactionOneValue = appropriateGetter.invoke(transactionOne);
      Object transactionTwoValue = appropriateGetter.invoke(transactionTwo);
      // Not much I can do with raw Objects...
    } catch (IntrospectionException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I need to somehow retrieve variables of the appropriate type, which, as shown above, will be a type whose instances are `Comparable` with instances of the same type. I have also fiddled a bit with the `Field.getType()` method after reading through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701751/java-reflection-get-class-of-field#:%7E:text=You%20need%20Field%23getType(),type%20of%20the%20object%20itself.) answer but I haven't had much luck. Any ideas?

// Edit: Addressing @0xh3xa's comment about the casting to `Comparable`. The code compiles as long as the `Comparable` type is unparameterized, but of course IntelliJ warns that the use of the type is raw, unparameterized. Perhaps a more elegant solution would be available?

[image: Unparameterized use of Comparable.]

Comment: _"enum I have created with about 300 different currency symbols"_ - Code smell. Currency symbols change (not often, but they do). This should be an externally loaded map.

Comment: Why did you not declare another list sorted by the `key` and check the equality with the `transactionDtos`?

Comment: `Comparable transactionOneValue = (Comparable) appropriateGetter.invoke(transactionOne)`

Comment: @0xh3xa offered a good suggestion. You always want the test code to be simpler than the code being tested, or else a bug in the test could mask a bug in the code by performing a false positive.

Comment: The issue is that I need to go from name of field to value returned by the appropriate getter. E.g, if the field is `"id"` I need to be able to call the getter `TransactionDto::getId()`. But I'm having trouble retrieving the appropriate type because I have to use reflection, and `Method.invoke()` returns raw `Object`s. I need a way to go from name of field to return type of the appropriate getter, and I need to do this whether I use my own way or the one suggested by @Oxh3xa ;) To be clear, this CAN be done with a `switch` statement or a chain of `if`-`else`s, but that's not maintainable.

Comment: Added an edit to address @0xh3xa's idea of casting to `Comparable`.

Comment: Sorry, yes I forgot about `Comparable` being generic. This can be solved with a generic method.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76700649/edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by making the method generic and adding casts:

```
private <T extends Comparable<T>> int compareFieldsInGivenOrder(TransactionDto transactionOne, TransactionDto transactionTwo,
                                      String sortByField, SortOrder sortOrder){
    try {
        PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(sortByField, TransactionDto.class);
        Method appropriateGetter = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T transactionOneValue = (T) appropriateGetter.invoke(transactionOne);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T transactionTwoValue = (T) appropriateGetter.invoke(transactionTwo);
        return sortOrder == SortOrder.ASC ? transactionOneValue.compareTo(transactionTwoValue) :
                transactionTwoValue.compareTo(transactionOneValue);
    } catch (IntrospectionException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Note that this results in unchecked cast warnings, which this example suppresses. However, if this code is only ever called with `Comparable` property names, it won't throw exceptions at runtime. Using reflection is inherently unchecked, so hopefully this is an acceptable compromise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit puzzled why you need such a method. Why doesn't your caller simply do:

```
    Comparators.isInOrder(transactionDtos, Comparator.comparing(t -> t.getAmount()))
```

if you find that too verbose, static imports can shorten this to:

```
    isInOrder(transactionDtos, comparing(t -> t.getAmount()))
```

That's shorter than the call to your utility method, and fully type checked by the compiler. Also, refactoring tools understand this method call, so a rename field refactoring will automatically update the test.

Comment: The issue is that I need to go from the field name, in this case, "amount", to the appropriate getter, using reflection, and `Method.invoke()` will return an `Object`, which CANNOT be used as the target of the lambda expression that you have applied inside `Comparator.comparing()`.

Comment: ... and *why* do you "need" to pass the sort key as a string, foregoing type checking and refactoring support?

Comment: Because this is a test case for a REST API Controller, for paginated queries, where the user provides the name of the field to sort by, as a `String` parameter!

Comment: ... and the test code doesn't hard code that value? I mean, calling `collectionIsSortedByFieldInGivenDirection(list, "amount", ASC)` isn't that different from calling `collectionIsSortedByFieldInGivenDirection(list, t -> t.getAmount(), ASC)` ...

Comment: PS: I do hope your REST Controller does some validation on that string before incorporating it into an SQL statement, so it doesn't give rise to an SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: The logic indeed performs validation before the persistence layer is reached.